# JavaFX TreeTableColumn: how to trigger column resizing and keep a new width

Tags: javafx

The question is in the title: is it possible to catch the resize of column (`TreeTableColumn`) to apply a new column size?

Answer (score 0):

Add a Listener to the columns width property. Something like this:

```
col.widthProperty().addListener(e->{
            if(!running.get()) {
                running.set(true);
                Runnable task = () -> {
                    try {Thread.sleep(2000);} catch (InterruptedException exc) {    }
                    Platform.runLater( () -> {
                            col.setPrefWidth(79);
                            col.setPrefWidth(80);
                    });
                    running.set(false);
                    System.out.println("done");
                };  
                new Thread(task).start();
            }
        });
```

If the prefWidth is just set to the previous value nothing happens. It has to actually change before the column resizes.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Hmmm, why to call `col.setPrefWidth(som_value)` twice? Why to call `sleep` for 2 secs? Looking at this code snippet, you'd tell yourself: "Wow, it is really readable, this Java code" :). I'll take a try and see f it works...

Comment: The delay is to avoid a resize after every single pixel. To stop the user from resizing altogether col.setResizable(false) is the right solution

Comment: Where the `running` variable comes from?

Comment: it's just a SimpleBooleanProperty

Comment: So, which value it should be set to or which constructor should be used in this case?

Comment: I didn't get the  answer why set up `prefWidth` twice either. Any clues?

Comment: It does not work and raises `java.lang.RuntimeException: TreeTableColumn.prefWidth : A bound value cannot be set`.